# postfix fails sending mails with clamav

Tags: postfix, clamav

I have a problem on my server running postfix with ClamAV, it doesn't send nor receives mails since yesterday, which is a really big deal for us..

So I checked the mail.log file and found out that all log lines were about ClamAV, so I tried to stop both

```
 /etc/init.d/clamav-daemon stop
/etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop
```

**But the second one freezes** and service is not stopped.. I can't restart the server itself but can eventually restart postfix if required. How can I stop and completely remove clamAV ? Thank you very much !

EDIT
Running on Debian, here is the output of ps aux | grep clamav
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your system is an ubuntu or debian or something like that, but i think you can use this commands to kill the clamav:

```
ps aux | grep clamav
```

and after that you just kill that process with this

```
kill -9 <clamav_id>
```

And you find in the postfix/main.cf file a line

```
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

or
   content_filter = clamav

Just comment out and restart postfix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But my problem is that there are a lot of clamav process still running, and I dont know which one to stop.. Edited my answer !

Comment: The freshclam is the updater you can kill it. The clamscan is the virus scanner you can kill too because if it frozen that stopping to restart the clamav.  I think the clamav-wrapper started the clamsan so you can kill that too. And you can kill the stop commands too. The crons maybe try to update the clamav with the frasclam thats why try to restart and that froses. You can try with yourself to update to see the error.

Comment: Ok so I actually have a much bigger problem where amavis completely crashed because it lost its DB connexion, clamAV is unkillable and postfix doesnt work anymore. Life's good, thanks a lot anyways !

Comment: oh oh. okay. good luck with that!